# jQuery CAD software

Tags: jquery, 3d, cad

Our client recently discovered this site:
http://mydeco.com/3d-planner/

It has a very, very fancy and well put together 3d CAD web app that appears to be written using jQuery and no flash/java.

I've had a fairly good look through the source but can't seem to find if they've used an off the shelf solution / open source thing to do it or if they have in fact had a proprietary bit of software written to them. It looks proprietary to me after doing several searches on keywords used in the code etc..

Does anyone know of anything out there like this (or this?)

Thanks!
John.

Comment: Never seen it before but it looks great indeed. Please let us know if you find more information.

Answer (score 4):

[shapesmith](http://www.shapesmith.net) is a browser-based 3D design application based on webgl that might interest you. The sources are available on [github](https://github.com/bjnortier/shapesmith).